# jQuery star rating causing page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem after adding button on my star rating. Every time when I click on the star, my page getting jumpy and scroll to the top. How can I prevent this behavior?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var rate=null;
        $(".one-star, .two-stars, .three-stars, .four-stars, .five-stars").click(function() {
             rate = $(this).html();
             $("#submit_rating").fadeIn("slow");
             $("#current_rating").width(rate*30);
        });
        $('#submit_rating').click(function(){
                $.ajax({data: ({ action: 'save_rating', rating: rate, listing_id: <?php echo $id; ?>}), success: function() { window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->escape(URL); ?>'; }});
                return false;
        });
    });
```

you can see my problem here: http://duniakita.org/starrating/

Comment: Is there a postback or it simply scroll to the top as if you programmed it that way ?

Comment: I'm not sure.. the original script will automatically submit your rating once you click on the star. it only happened after I added a submit button for confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use `e.preventDefault` on the `*-stars` click.

```
$(".one-star, .two-stars, .three-stars, .four-stars, .five-stars").click(function(e) {
    rate = $(this).html();
    $("#submit_rating").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#current_rating").width(rate*30);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thanks for really quick reply! but it still wont work. I added link to my question. maybe you can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Ah, ok. The `e.preventDefault();` should probably go on the event that fires when you click the stars. I updated my answer.

Comment: What I usually do with jQuery only links is set href="javascript:;" instead of href="#".  But it's good practice to use preventDefault() anyway

Comment: wow thanks a million Ryan! it's solved the issue. I love this community!

Comment: @Dave thanks for the tips! I'm just starting again after leaving programming for over 4 years and having problem to make myself familiar with new stuff and recall what I've learned before